# Rails: Faye works for me, but still gives some JS error in the console for some unknown reason, Should I be worried?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, websocket, faye, private-pub

I'm using [Private_Pub](https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub) gem which is built on [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/), and I'm using a another app for the Faye which is provided by this [blog](http://joshcrews.com/blog/2013/06/07/running-private-pub-slash-faye-server-on-heroku/) [the project](https://github.com/IamNaN/heroku_private_pub) that I found. to get Faye running on an app and my actual site on another app.

The error in FireFox console:

```
The connection to ws://xxxxxxxxxxx.herokuapp.com/faye was interrupted while the page was loading. Faye.js
```

and in Chrome:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://xxxxxxxxxxx.herokuapp.com/faye' failed: One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 1, reserved2 = 0, reserved3 = 0
```

on the Chat (Faye) app log I get this in the log :

```
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path=/faye host=xxxxxxxxxxx.herokuapp.com request_id=xxxxxxxxxxx fwd="xxxxxxxxxxx" dyno=web.1 connect=31ms service=30112ms status=503 bytes=0
```

any suggestions: ?

I have added an `after_filter` in the `application_controller` as well to allow the domain request

Comment: I am also having this problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hey @ajbraus, yes I did find a solution :)! I will write it as an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, the `Rails Apps` need to let each other access or let's say ping each other. In order to do that, we have to use something like [CORS](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors), to allow AJAX Request from Other Domain.
Here is a simpler way that I used to go allow method accesses [article](http://www.kevinhq.com/2012/06/rails-allow-ajax-request-from-other.html), it might sound confusing at first.

To do perform this on both sides, you need to create an actual complete app for the `Faye` as well, unlike what is given on the Faye chat server Repo I've attached in my question.

- Step 1 :

In the Actual/Main App include this in your `application_controller.rb`

```
  before_filter :cors_preflight_check
  after_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers
  #For all responses in this controller, return the CORS access control headers.
  def cors_set_access_control_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://YOURFAYEAPP.com'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = 'http://YOURFAYEAPP.com'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
  end
  # If this is a preflight OPTIONS request, then short-circuit the
  # request, return only the necessary headers and return an empty
  # text/plain.
  def cors_preflight_check
    if request.method == :options
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://YOURFAYEAPP.com'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS'
      headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = 'http://YOURFAYEAPP.com'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
      render :text => '', :content_type => 'text/plain'
    end
end
```

- Step 2:

  on the Faye app side include the same thing in the `application_controller.rb`, but change the domain name to the Original/Actual/Main Rails app.

In that way, both can send and receive requests.
Don't put `*` instead of the request `parameter`, it's a security issue. You can cut down the `methods` to only `Get` and `Post`.

Answer (score 2):

This was an issue with my application also, heroku has a timeout of 30 and if the faye.ru/config.ru has timeout set more than 30 this error would come. try reducing it to 25 or something.
`faye_server = Faye::RackAdapter.new(:mount => '/faye', :timeout => 25)`

Comment: I enabled websockets on both sides using this command:
`$ heroku labs:enable websockets -a myapp`
And then I used CORS in my `Application Controller` to allow access for both of the applications. The chat and the main app.